# How to get javascript to insert input forms in a field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried writing this several different times, but it's just not working. Is there any evident error from the code below? I'm trying to get it to insert a new form input with a changing name value.

```
<script>
    $("document").ready(function(){
        console.log('wtf is going on');
        var i = 0;
        var insert = '<div class="form-group"> +
                <label>Categories</label>+
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category' +i+'" value="test"></div>';
        $(".lolz").click(function(){
            i++;
            $(".lolz").before(insert)});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Newlines in a JS string will give you problems.

Comment: Multiline strings in JavaScript aren't supported like that. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript. Next time, open your browsers console using F12, and you'll see these sorts of errors straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your newlines in the `insert` string:

```
var insert = '<div class="form-group">
              <label>Categories</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category' + i +
             '" value="test"></div>';
```

JavaScript doesn't support multi-line strings, without telling the interpreter explicitly that the string is multi-line.

Try replacing those lines with:

```
var insert = '<div class="form-group"> \
              <label>Categories</label> \
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category' + i + 
             '" value="test"></div>';
```

The slash (`\`) "escapes" the following line-break, which basically tells the JavaScript interpreter "This string continues on the next line".

A slightly more maintainace-friendly way, would be to use string concatenation, like this:

```
var insert = '<div class="form-group">' +
             '<label>Categories</label>' +
             '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="category' + i + 
             '" value="test"></div>';
```

Answer (score -1):

try this way....

```
var insert = '<div class="form-group">'
              insert += ' <label>Categories</label>'
               insert += '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="category' +i+'" value="test"></div>';
```